# What is the best CSV format to write json in JAVA?

Tags: java, csv

I would like to write the following JSON into CSV file using JAVA. What is the best CSV format?

```
"order_items": {
    "items": [{
      "name1": "I1",
      "name2": "I2",
      "name3": "I3"
    }, {
      "name1": "J1",
      "name2": "J2",
      "name3": "J3"
    }],
    "date": "XXXX-xx-xx",
    "time": "hh:min:ss"
  }
```

Comment: Since CSV is only two-dimensional (rows of cells), but JSON can be arbitrarily nested, this will become _really awkward_ in the general case.

Comment: Use commas between values :)  I assume you're asking what to do with the "items" array of objects.  That depends on how the CSV data will be used.  Will it be imported into a spreadsheet to be viewed by a person? In that case you should focus on the layout so the aggregation is apparent.  If the data is to be used by other software then you'll need to write out a flat view which includes all relevant values for each item of interest.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is hierarchical structure while CSV is plain. This means that CSV can hold only similar data that belong to the same type. In your case you can present items as following:

```
name1, namee2, name3
I1, I2, I3
j1, j2, j3
```

However you cannot put date and time into the same structure. You can save them separately (for example in separate file) or de-normalize your data saving date and time for each line:

```
name1, namee2, name3, date, time
I1, I2, I3, XXXX-xx-xx, hh:min:ss
j1, j2, j3, "XXXX-xx-xx, hh:min:ss
```

IMHO looks ugly, but sometimes useful.

If you save your CSV as file you probably can encode date and time into the file name, e.g. create file that holds items (see first example) with name "`data.XXXX-xx-xx.hh:min:ss.csv`"

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to write all in one line and still differentiate the "items" array values? Basically I asked to write a single line per JSON.

Comment: Take a look on my second example. This can be achieved only if data (date and time) is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: None

**Long answer:**

CSV was designed to cater two dimension. To abuse it for your purpose you need to define a fixed dimension JSon (As you probably know JSon can be of arbitrary hierarchy. For example if JSon is three dimension like `items:{arr1:[item1, item2, item3], arr2:[item1, item2, item3]}` then it will have three delimiters. Let say delimiters are  comma, hyphen and plus sign (for sake of explanation) then CSV will be
`items-arr1+item1,item2,item3-arr2+item1,item2, item3`

I would not recommend that for reason said above. I suggest you find a way to save file as sheer JSon or somehow serialize/deserialize it than mess with it that way!